# Is it beneficial to do moderate Walking after dinner?

Tags: walking

I have developed a habit of walking for half an hour, after about an hour after dinner.
I dont walk fast, its just the normal speed that I usually walk.
I think this will help in digestion & give me sound sleep.
Now I have read various articles on the internet some of which are against this habit while some support this practice.
Speaking scientifically, since walking in moderate speed results in vibrations to the stomach this results in better contact between food & acids in stomach. But this is what I can think of. Any advice on this regard would be helpful.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physical activity at any time of the day is good for you, only if it is not too close to the sleep time just because one might be too active to fall asleep. Ideally half an hour before sleep time should be the cut off.

Some people say that walking after having food interferes with digestion, but I say sitting idle just after having food is even worse. Majority the blood sugar and energy infused by the food eaten is more likely to convert into fat if somebody just stays inactive or sleeps right away. Its much better to stay moving throughout the day off and on to maintain a good metabolic rate and digestion.

Answer (score 0):

The digestive issues may be a problem for some people with certain GI problems (heartburn, for example), but just try it out. There's no reason to preemptively modify your activity with no evidence that you need to. I can't imagine light walking would do any damage that you couldn't fix by just changing your behaviour if you notice a problem.